# Matrix rotation/translation/scaling in openGL

Tags: opengl, vector, matrix, rotational-matrices

I need to write an openGL matrix that rotates a point (x,y,z,w) around a given vector
(for example , (1,2,-2)) by a 45 degree angle, how would I do that using matrices multiplication over the identity matrix ? (rotations , scaling, translations...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is called [axis angle rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation), the easiest is using the quaternion route:

the equivalent quaternion is `sin(angle/2)*x, sin(angle/2)*y, sin(angle/2)*z, cos(angle/2)`

then you use the matrix in the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion) to obtain the rotation matrix

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Eigen linear algebra library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/), specifically [Eigen::AxisAngle](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AngleAxis.html).